# Prevent Lightbox close on child click

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, parent-child, lightbox

I have some code where a div opens on element click with another div inside it. I want it to close when I click outside of the child div but it is closing when I click on either.

HTML:

```
  <div id="gallerybox">

            <div id="webbox1" ><h1 class="codetext">Hand<br> Coded</h1></div>
            <div id="webbox2"><h1 id="musich1">Wordpress<br>Sites</h1></div>
            <div id="webbox3"><h1 id="musich1">Mobile Web<br> Apps</h1></div>

            <div id="lightbox"><div id="webbox1result"></div></div>

        </div>
```

Css:

```
 #lightbox{
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
z-index: 99;
position: absolute;
display: none;
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: black;
 }
 #webbox1result{
height: 280%;
width: 90%;

position: absolute;
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: aqua;
z-index: 100;
margin-top: 7%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
  $("#webbox1").click(function(){ 
$("#lightbox").css("display", "block");
} 
 );
$("#lightbox").click(function(){ 
$("#lightbox").css("display", "none");
} 
 );
```

Comment: You can check if the target was the inner div and then return w/o applying the css, is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your `click` to include a parameter, like `e` in the following example: `.click(function(e) { ... });`

You can then add `if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;` to check if the target of the click is specifically `#lightbox`. If not, the function ends.

**Code:**

```
$("#lightbox").click(function(e) {
    if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
    $("#lightbox").css("display", "none");
});
```

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/th8gfe3v/

Answer (score -1):

I guess the solution to your problem would be something like

jQuery:

```
$("#webbox1").click(function(){ 
    $("#lightbox").toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d56n492x/